# Copying Link and insert into browser

Tags: python

I have a python that shows me emails, now I want the bot to
Find the link and inserts it into the browser.
I've already tried to find ways on the internet, but unfortunately without success!

The link is displayed to me in the console, I just don't know how to copy the link and paste it into my browser

maybe someone has an idea or rather said someone knows what I have to research?

```
 import imaplib
import email
from email.header import decode_header
import webbrowser
import os

# account credentials
username = "EMAIL"
password = "PASSWORD"

def clean(text):
    # clean text for creating a folder
    return "".join(c if c.isalnum() else "_" for c in text)



# create an IMAP4 class with SSL 
imap = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL("outlook.office365.com")
# authenticate
imap.login(username, password)


status, messages = imap.select("INBOX")
# number of top emails to fetch
N = 3
# total number of emails
messages = int(messages[0])


for i in range(messages, messages-N, -1):
    # fetch the email message by ID
    res, msg = imap.fetch(str(i), "(RFC822)")
    for response in msg:
        if isinstance(response, tuple):
            # parse a bytes email into a message object
            msg = email.message_from_bytes(response[1])
            # decode the email subject
            subject, encoding = decode_header(msg["Subject"])[0]
            if isinstance(subject, bytes):
                # if it's a bytes, decode to str
                subject = subject.decode(encoding)
            # decode email sender
            From, encoding = decode_header(msg.get("From"))[0]
            if isinstance(From, bytes):
                From = From.decode(encoding)
            print("Subject:", subject)
            print("From:", From)
            # if the email message is multipart
            if msg.is_multipart():
                # iterate over email parts
                for part in msg.walk():
                    # extract content type of email
                    content_type = part.get_content_type()
                    content_disposition = str(part.get("Content-Disposition"))
                    try:
                        # get the email body
                        body = part.get_payload(decode=True).decode()
                    except:
                        pass
                    if content_type == "text/plain" and "attachment" not in content_disposition:
                        # print text/plain emails and skip attachments
                        print(body)
                    elif "attachment" in content_disposition:
                        # download attachment
                        filename = part.get_filename()
                        if filename:
                            folder_name = clean(subject)
                            if not os.path.isdir(folder_name):
                                # make a folder for this email (named after the subject)
                                os.mkdir(folder_name)
                            filepath = os.path.join(folder_name, filename)
                            # download attachment and save it
                            open(filepath, "wb").write(part.get_payload(decode=True))
            else:
                # extract content type of email
                content_type = msg.get_content_type()
                # get the email body
                body = msg.get_payload(decode=True).decode()
                if content_type == "text/plain":
                    # print only text email parts
                    print(body)
            if content_type == "text/html":
                # if it's HTML, create a new HTML file and open it in browser
                folder_name = clean(subject)
                if not os.path.isdir(folder_name):
                    # make a folder for this email (named after the subject)
                    os.mkdir(folder_name)
                filename = "index.html"
                filepath = os.path.join(folder_name, filename)
                # write the file
                open(filepath, "w").write(body)
                # open in the default browser
                webbrowser.open(filepath)
            print("="*100)
# close the connection and logout
imap.close()
imap.logout()
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you want, but maybe

```py
import webbrowser
webbrowser.open(url)
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/webbrowser.html